# Custom Function in Tensorflow Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Lets assume I want to apply a `function` on a `tensorflow tensor` in the following way:

```
|2 7 4|      |f(2) f(7) f(4)|
|6 7 2| ---> |f(6) f(7) f(2)| ---> with f(x)=2+e^x
|6 8 8|      |f(6) f(8) f(8)|
```

How can i realize that in a tensorflow layer, with GPU support, paralellize-able to get the needed speed. A way with `tf.py_func` is easy, with numpy, but slow. I would prefere a fully `tensorflow` based solution --> `tf GPU speedup`.

Answer (score 0):

I think i can answer this question myself, my function looks like this:

```
Function of interest: f(a1,a2,a3,x)=a1+a2*e^(x/a3)
```

The corresponding tensorflow code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Input data
img = tf.reshape(tf.range(5*5*1, dtype=tf.float32), [1, 5, 5, 1])

a1=2.5
a2=10
a3=75

img=tf.math.divide(img,a3)
img=tf.math.exp(img)
img=tf.math.multiply(img,a2)
img=tf.math.add(img,a1)
```

Check the results:

```
print(img)
```